# ios delegate method not being called

Tags: ios, class, delegates

I have two Classes - say `Class1` and `Class2`

`Class1` has button which when pressed does a push segue to `Class2`.

Also, when the button is pressed a network call is being done on another class.

`Class1` code :

```
- (IBAction)sellPressed:(id)sender
{
    SPNNetworkEngine *networkEngine = [[SPNNetworkEngine alloc] init];
    networkEngine.delegate = self;
    [networkEngine getFarePrice];
}
```

In `Network` class, I have :

In `.h` file

```
@protocol SPNNetworkEngineDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) farePriceReceivedWithDetails:(id) farePrice;

@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
- (void) getFarePrice;
```

In `.m` file

```
- (void) getFarePrice
{
 ...........
 .......

  //After all the operations, I delegate
  if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(farePriceReceivedWithDetails:)])
             [delegate farePriceReceivedWithDetails:cost];
  }
}
```

And in `Class2` I have,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     SPNNetworkEngine *networkEngine = [[SPNNetworkEngine alloc] init];
    networkEngine.delegate = self;
}

// Delegate method
- (void) farePriceReceivedWithDetails:(id)farePrice
{
   NSLog(@"FarePrice %@", farePrice);
}
```

The `delegate` method in `Class2` is never called. What have I done wrong here?

But when I write the delegate method `-(void)farePriceReceivedWithDetails:(id)farePrice` in `Class1`, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Coding approch is wrong You alloc SPNNetworkEngine class in Your Class1 and set delegate of SPNNetworkEngine is self. so The delegate is fire in class1. But you want this method in class2 so you have to assign this delegate with class2 object.

Second point is you have to Change this line with this

```
@protocol SPNNetworkEngineDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) farePriceReceivedWithDetails:(id) farePrice;

@end

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SPNNetworkEngineDelegate> delegate;
- (void) getFarePrice;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should retain this object in Class1.h as instance variable. So that it will be alive till that class object exist. What you are doing currently is simply allocating it in a method. once the method executed & finished, it will be deallocated. So your delegate call back will not work.

So avoid this line

```
  SPNNetworkEngine *networkEngine = [[SPNNetworkEngine alloc] init];
```

change the above code to like below

Declare in Class1

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) SPNNetworkEngine *networkEngine;
```

Then do

```
 self.networkEngine = [[SPNNetworkEngine alloc] init];
```

Comment: Ok, made some sense there. Thanks. But I need to execute the method in Class2.

Comment: class2 is a UIViewController or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

In the Class1 you are calling to `[networkEngine getTestPrice]` and I think that mean the `[networkEngine getFarePrice]` function (because is where you call the delegate)

In Class2 you must call the same function: `[networkEngine getTestPrice]`

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the SPNNetworkEngineDelegate to the list of delegates in the Class2.h?

i.e.

```
@interface Class2 : UIViewController <SPNNetworkEngineDelegate>
```